# how to load local json file into javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to load the JSON file into a javascript file.

```
This is my folder structure:

Test
|
|---static
|     |
|     |----js
|           |
|           |--- test.js
|
|
|--- instance
     |
     |-- file.json.
```

Here " Test " is my root folder, In that, I have 2 folders

i) static

ii) instance.

In the instance folder, I have a file called file.json.

In static I have one more folder called Js, In that folder have test.js

I WANT TO LOAD THE file.json in test.js HOW CAN I DO THAT?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As long as the contents of `Test` is served by a web server, you can do `fetch("/instance/file.json").then(r => r.json()).then(data => { /* do something */ });` In case the file is indeed local, this won't work though. You need to actually host the website.

Comment: Chris G made a good point. Are you serving your files with a web server? If you want to do this locally, NodeJS is your only option.